# how do i like a message/notification with the linkedin api?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I have an application that authenticates users through the LinkedIn API. My questions:

- is it possible for an application to like messages to all users who authorized it?
- is it possible to get like list of a message to a subset of the application users?

I've been looking for a while, and can't find anything.

Comment: Bit of clarifications would be helpful.. What u mean exactly by "to like messages to all users"?

Comment: is it possible for an application to like a message/post/share send by user or user's friend using linkedin group api? 
is it possible to get like list of a message send by user or user's friend using linkedin group api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via the [Groups API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api) of the [LinkedIn APIs](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis), you can like a post in a particular group using the following JavaScript code (XXXX is the particular post id):

```
IN.API.Raw('/posts/XXXX/relation-to-viewer/is-liked')
  .method('PUT')
  .body("true")
  .result(function(result) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  })
  .error(function(result) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  });
```

However, keep in mind that likes should not be automated but user initiated - only users who have authenticated your app should be liking posts, and only when they manually choose to do so. Writing a script that automatically likes all posts from any user that posts a message from your app is against the LinkedIn API terms of service.

Comment: Well you never specified that in your question

Answer (score 0):

Can't confirm for sure but maybe this link about [likes](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/commenting-reading-comments-and-likes-network-updates) can help u and give a clues about possible options.. Reported example you can find [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/14970#comment-14970) or [here](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/15126#comment-15126). However I have no guaranty that this works cause I am not author of those posts.. Maybe u will find better and more accurate answer at LinkedIn API forum..

Hope it helped a bit.. Cheers

Comment: feel free to accept one of answers.. It will rise your rate, it will make whole community better place.. ;)